# Java web app page load monitor

Tags: java, websphere, monitoring

Is there any way to monitor client page load time on server during the system runtime? Specially, is there such tool that could be integrated with the WebSphere server?

For example, there were 1000 page loads during an hour and I calculate the average time. If the average time exceeds the set number, the email is sent automatically to the admin. This is not hard to implement at all, but is there a way I could track the page load time from user on the server side?

I was thinking of sending a response after page is loaded via JS to the serverside and analyse it over there, so it could be integrated to every web-service or controller I have. But is there any tool or something like that, that could do such an action?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.

The Load testing apps is not what I need.

EDIT

I've already surfed through this question - [Automated Monitoring of User-perceived Page Load Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108164/automated-monitoring-of-user-perceived-page-load-time) , but still, it doesn't fully answer my problem :(

Comment: I thought that's what [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/application-monitoring) (or similar tools) do. I've never used it though, so it's just a rough impression.

Comment: Yeah, NewRelic does pretty much the same, but there is now way to embed it into the application. It is an overloaded app, I need a lighter one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an interesting JavaWorld article with sample code to monitor user time, tested with WebSphere 6.1: [Measuring Web application response time: Meet the client](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-2008/jw-11-measuring-client-response.html).

> In this article Srijeeb Roy introduces a lightweight approach to capturing the end user's experience of application response time. He also shows you how to send and log client-side response times on a server for future analysis

[image]

You should implement, however, the average calculation and alerting.